# How to preview initial file on React dropzone component

Tags: typescript, react-hooks

React 18: I am trying to create a flow where I would convert Base64 string image coming from an API response into a File object JS and display as a preview on React dropzone component, but I am not being able to preview it after generating file with Base64 string.

I am getting a map error when trying to preview it. It seems to be missing a preview containing the Blob URL and path attribute.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you have described it seems like you're facing two issues:

1. You're trying to map an object using `.map()` and that is why you're getting a map error. In order to fix it, test the code bellow and take a look at the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries);

```js
const object1 = {
  a: 'somestring',
  b: 42
};

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(object1)) {
  console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
}
```

Or convert it into an Array

```js
const map = new Map(Object.entries(obj));
```

Or

```js
const entries = Object.entries(obj);
```

2. It seems like the second error is being caused because you don't have the preview URL in your object, resulting in nothing to display. In order to fix it, please add this code after creating a Blob file.

```js
files.map(file => ({
        ...file,
        preview: URL.createObjectURL(file)
      }))
```

ps. The result of 1 and 2 might be dependent on each other.

Comment: Hi thank you so much for your time and for sharing this. I did work precisely! Much appreciated!